# I want to have a part name in more than one line in the ToC, but then the lower lines aren't aligned as the first one

Tags: table-of-contents, parts, alignment

I want to have a part name in more than one line in the ToC, but then the lower lines aren't aligned as the first one. How can I fix that? See pic below.
The \documentclass is a report.

[image: ToC part alignment]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  How this is done will depend on what `\documentclass` you are using, and you haven't specified that.  (Recommendation: Use ragged right when supporting long toc entries.  Otherwise, they can look perfectly horrible with very uneven word spacing.)

Comment: I use report document class.

Comment: Could you please post a minimal compilable code that we can play with?

Comment: I don't know how this could help you, but alright, here it is
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{part1}
\include{part2}

\end{document}

and then chapters and parts are in part1 and part2

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. you can replace `2em` with a more precise dimension.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter 
\patchcmd{\l@part}{\parindent}{\hangindent 2em \parindent}{}{\err}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Here is a part name in more than one line in the ToC, with the lower lines  aligned as the first one}
\chapter{A chapter of foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thaaaaaank youuuu very much!

Comment: @MakPavičević you're welcome,